# Get all files from SFTP directory and sub directory with extension is not working.

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using following code to get the files and it works for the directory but I would like to traverse thru sub directories too and when I put -recurse it stops working.

```
Import-Module –Name "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Posh-SSH" -Verbose

$passwordTest = "Password"
$securePasswordTest = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordTest -AsPlainText -Force
$credentialsTest = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("USername", $securePasswordTest)
$sessionTest = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName SFTP -Credential $credentialsTest -AcceptKey
$sourceTest = "/u01/G"
$destinationTest= "F:\SourceOLTP\"

Get-SFTPChildItem $sessionTest -Path $sourceTest | ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.Fullname -like '*.csv') 
    {  
        Get-SFTPFile $sessionTest -RemoteFile $_.FullName -LocalPath $destinationTest -Overwrite 
    }

    write-output $_.FullName 

}


Remove-SFTPSession $sessionTest -Verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

The recurse switch on `Get-SFTPChildItem` appears to be `-Recursive`.

Source: https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Get-SFTPChildItem.md

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but when I apply -Recursive it gives me an error.
Get-SFTPChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Recursive'

Comment: Ok. But that error doesn't appear when you do `-Recurse`? In what way does it stop working when you use `-Recurse`?

Comment: It gives me the different error when I use -Recurse.  A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Comment: Try `Get-SFTPChildItem -SFTPSession $sessionTest -Path $sourceTest -Recurse | ...`